# Selecting a particular record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sql server table as follows

- EmailId
- PersonId
- Email
- IsPreferred

A specific PersonId can have more than 1 email, in which case one of the email addresses MIGHT be preferred.  How can I select one email for each PersonId ensuring that if there is a preferred email that is the one selected.  If there is no preferred email for a PersonId any email can be selected.

Comment: Can I assume that `IsPreferred` is a `bit` column which allows nulls?

Comment: And if neither of two addresses is preferred, which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select with "ORDER BY ISPREFERRED DESC", then take the first result row.

Generally, in case ordering is not convenient this way, you may use a UNION of subqueries, with an additional "constant" value column "1", "2" .. in each part of the UNION, then sort (descending, so highest value comes first) on that column. Again, take the first one.

Comment: The other solutions will perform much better... For example Pertar Ivanov's solution will only scan the table (or index) one time whereas this union query is going to scan the table(or index) once for every subquery in the union

Answer (score 2):

```
select PersonId, EmailId from (
    select 
        PersonId,
        EmailId,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PersonId order by IsPreferred desc) as rnk
    from myTable
) as t
where t.rnk = 1
```

Comment: row_number is better than rank, in case you have more than one prefered emails.